# useEffect как componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

Есть ли возможность в функциональных компонентах React отслеживать момент только повторных изменений props. Те аналогично методу componentDidUpdate в классовых компонентах? Если вторым аргументом передавать список зависимостей props, то хук useEffect запустится также при первом рендеренге, а этого не хотелось бы. Делать проверку с использованием флага - также кажется не лучшим решением. Что посоветуете?

```
useEffect(() => {
       console.log('hook');
   }, [props.counter]);
```

Comment: Почему "не хотелось бы", что за задача?

Comment: Только внутри useEffect написать условие, а так то вообще это нормальное поведение

Comment: Возможно, если реструктурировать стейт, проблема исчезнет.

Comment: Например, эталонный-стейт и стейт-изменений

Comment: Есть список однотипных дочерних компонентов, а есть родительский компонент. В дочерний компонент нужно передать всем одинаковое начальное значение counter. Написав useEffect в родительском хук сработает один раз и передаст counter как props в дочерний. Но нужно отслеживать изменения counter в дочерним компоненте - писать useState в дочерний также. Получается нет смысла в родительском писать useState тк все равно сработает useState в дочернем при первом рендеринге

Comment: Спасибо откликнувшимся. Переделаю структуру немного

Answer (score 0):

Итак, начальное значение counter появляется в state родителя и приходит через props (или context) в дочерний. Оно так и продолжает это делать.

По ходу дела дочерний свой counter меняет, кладя себе в стейт.

Там, где counter используется, вызывается функция, дающая один из 2-х с приоритетом дочернего.

---

Альтернатива:

Можно использовать аргумент `useState(initial)`, но это менее гибко.

Т. к. с первым вариантом можно, например, учитывать время/версии: дочерний поменял, но родитель позже решил, что он правее со своим новым значением.